# mod-rewrite not working on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove "index.php" in the CodeIgniter URLs.

I have it working on my Mac (MAMP), but can’t get it working on my Ubuntu (Lucid) hosted server.

This works: mysite.com/index.php/home
But this generates 404 errors: mysite.com/home

I’ve followed the instructions from [this post](http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/remove-codeigniter-index-php.html) and included the following lines in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

- I’ve confirmed that mod-rewrite is loaded on Apache2.
- The .htaccess file is in the webroot (/var/www), which is also where my main index.php is.
- The .htaccess file permissions are: -rwxrwxr-x
- I've tried about 20 different posted answers for the .htaccess file, so I suspect there's something wrong with my overall Apache config on my hosted Ubuntu (Lucid) server.

What other Apache configs need to be set to make mod-rewrites work? 
My httpd.conf file is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to view the system-wide httpd.con and its included files? It's possible the configuration issue stems from there.

Comment: @Johnnie - not sure what you mean. I can "cat /etc/apache2/httpd.conf", but it's empty. That file's permission is:  -rw-r--r--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this on a .htaccess file, be sure to enable at least, `AllowOverride FileInfo` and `Options FollowSymLink` to your Apache configuration file.

On the subject of httpd.conf being empty, is just that you are using a Debian based distro, the place you should be looking for is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (that is the default virtualhost configuration file). Main server directives reside in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

(Oh! yes, your test case is working fine).

Comment: It works great! Thanks! I also needed to restart Apache afterwards. The key was knowing which file was the Apache config file in Ubuntu (not httpd.conf as mentioned in other posts)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see whether AllowOverride is set; a simple, *temporary*:

```
Deny from all
```

in your .htaccess works nicely as a testcase.